# Symfony custom form widget and validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, symfony

I'm trying to develop a form that a user can use to book my time.

I already found a [JS datepicker](https://github.com/bluppfisk/pickadate.js) that I like and adjusted/fixed to support the rather complicated logic behind my availability: e.g.

- on odd weeks, I only serve location A; on even weeks I only serve location B
- if the product ordered is not in stock (data from DB), the next two days are unavailable
- I must be able to set a holiday period
- If someone else booked a slot, that slot must become unavailable
- ...

Since I'm only just discovering Symfony, I'm not sure how to go about this.

I think that I could create a sort of *custom input type* for my form that handles the above logic (with DB calls and such), in order to create a valid form. However, to avoid people from messing with the HTML and submitting an unavailable slot to the DB, I also need to create a *custom validation method* that verifies whether the slot is still available when the user books it.

Is the above feasible with Symfony and is the proposed solution correct?